# Unable to deploy on GAE - App using vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements 1.7.0.0

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I am trying to integrate vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements and upgrading my GWT app to GWT SDK 2.8. This works absolutely fine on local dev environment when I use Java 8 (jdk1.8.0_111) 
When I try to deploy the app on GAE, I get the following errer

```
Unable to update app: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: com/vaadin/polymer/app/AppBoxElement.class in /Users/aadhaarmehrotra/git/rnlg-ims/RNLGPC/war/WEB-INF/lib/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar
```

Please suggest how this app can be deployed to appengine (using Eclipse GAE plugin). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fix for this issue.
'vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar' DOES require Java 8 and Appengine doesn't support Java 8 so we can not upload 'vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar' to appengine.

By removing it from /WEB-INF/lib and by adding 'vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.7.0.0.jar' dependency as an external JAR, the application could compile successfully and the generated JS files are only uploaded to Appengine.

By satisfying both Appengine and the JAR requirements, this app can be deployed to Appengine!!

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine doesn't support Java 8.

Consider using https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/

Comment: Technically just standard env GAE doesn't support java 8, flexible env (which you suggest and which, indeed, supports java 8) is still GAE :) https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs